# Could not find or load main class com.weekdays.claobj.Ann1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BPEC.png)My code is showing no compilation error but it fails while execution with below error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51590:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\ag186097\IdeaProjects\Prwatech\target\scala-2.11\classes;C:\Users\ag186097\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.8.jar com.weekdays.claobj.Ann1
**Error: Could not find or load main class com.weekdays.claobj.Ann1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.weekdays.claobj.Ann1**
```

I have tried setting the main folder as root folder still not getting executed

```
package com.weekdays.claobj

class Annon1Obj {

  var age:Int = 29

  def show():Unit = {

    println("this is the age of raju " + age)}

}

object Ann1{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var n = new Annon1Obj()

    n.show()

  }

}
```

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart might be the indexing problem your code looks fine.

Comment: still same error

Comment: I am able to execute the same file from command line

Comment: Jdk version 8 you need to run scala

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.scala-lang.org/download/

read the first step make sure you have JDK 8 installed.

if you have jdk 8 installed then you can go select jdk 8 as your project jdk.

file-> project structure -> there you will find a drop down where you will have the JDK you can change it.

Downgrade your jdk version to 8 it will work fine then.